# Generics Inheritance and field declaration (class<T> where T : class<T>)

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following class definition:

```
public abstract class BaseExample<T> where T : BaseExample<T>
{

    public abstract T Clone(T original);

}
```

and its inheritances

```
public class Example01 : BaseExample<Example01>
{
    public override Example01 Clone(Example01 original)
    {
        return this; // not the actual implementation
    }
}

public class Example02 : BaseExample<Example02>
{
    public override Example02 Clone(Example02 original)
    {
        return this; // not the actual implementation
    }
}
```

How to declare a variable with the type or the base class? Since the following declaration doesn't compile:

```
private BaseExample<T> declarationA;
    private BaseExample<T>  declarationA;
    private BaseExample declarationB;
```

Comment: `BaseExample<T>` won't work unless the compiler knows what `T` is (meaning it's within a generic class or method), and `BaseExample` is not a type.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Currently it seems like you should use the Example01/02 classes in the declaration but it seems like you do not want that.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted the compile error for us. Use the link at the bottom of your question to edit your question.

Comment: @Stilgar I need to have a instance of BaseExample that could receive both Example01 or Example02 values. e.g.: BaseExample a = new Example01();

Comment: And what would the return type of declarationA.Clone() be in this hypothetical case?

Comment: @Stilgar Oh, I think I see the problem with my aproach now, isn't possible to do this that way. Anyway, thank you all for the helping. There is a way to make the method generic instead of the class?

Comment: I still don't know what you are trying to achieve. Obviously you can't have a static type that is neither generic nor known at compile time. Maybe you want a interface implemented by Example classes?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have a instance of `BaseExample` that could receive both `Example01` or `Example02` values. e.g.: `BaseExample a = new Example01()`

You can't - `BaseExample<Example01>` and `BaseExample<Example02>` are different types.  There's not a base type (other than `object`) that could hold either type.

Suppose you could:

```
BaseExample a = new Example01();
```

what would the return type of `a.Clone()` return?

If your code is within a generic class ot method, then you could:

```
public T MyMethod<T>(T value) where T : BaseExample<T>
{
    BaseExample<T> a = value;
    return value.Close();
}
```

But you'd then have to specify the type when calling the method, e.g.

```
Example01 a1 = new Example01();
Example01 a2 = MyMethod(a1);  // MyMethod<Example01> is inferred by the compiler
```

Comment: Oh, I think the generic method is the solution to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It won't work as whatever you assign to generic type `T` cannot really ever be `BaseExample<T>`.

```
BaseExample<int>  declarationA;
```

in case above `int` can't really be `BaseExample<int>` (`int` != `BaseExample<int>`)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, because `Generic<T1>` and `Generic<T2>` are different classes, you cannot assign them to the same variable.

One way I get around this is to use a non-generic base class, such that

```
public abstract class BaseExample { ... }
public abstract class BaseExmmple<T> : BaseExample
    where T : BaseExample<T>
{ ... }
```

This can be made more safe by implementing an `internal abstract` member, such that outside classes cannot implement `BaseExample`.

If you wish to be able to call `.Clone()` from an object held in a variable of the non-generic type, you should implement an `object`-returning form which is wrapped by the generic class to call the generic form.